# operating 8051 ports from a internet

Tags: serial-port, microcontroller, 8051, serial-communication

I am connecting relays at ports of microcontroller 8051. i want to operate them from website.
so, i want to tx/rx their status to computer and then upload to web server.

Something  [like this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kV2zHsQbYxI&feature=watch_response) but i have limitation to using 8051 for my school project.

I found that "Pyserial" can be used to receive data to a computer. is there any other way to do it?

i have some knowledge of c , php, javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your capabilities it is hard to answer such a general question.

If you are familiar with Python and can program the 8051, it should be relatively easy to have the 8051 receive a byte and control up to 8 outputs based on the bit values in the Byte and then have the 8051 echo the value back to the PC for output status confirmation.

I have not used Pyserial or Python but from what I have read Pyserial should be  able to easily send and receive byte in this fashion.

Good Luck.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
I have started off with [link](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/17926.html)
since i am familiar with php.

Comment: It looks like this php class will probably work although I have not tried anything like this.  I would recommend you try to make a simple loopback serial cable with pins 2 and 3 tied together and see if you can send a byte and then receive it.  If this works, then you can put the 8051 on the end of the cable and make a simple loopback program for the 8051 which sends whatever byte it receives.  The next step would be to program the 8051 to control 8 relays based on the byte received and to send a byte of status info back to the server.